# Blender game: How you can make an object to emit light?

Tags: game-engine, light

In Blender Game how you can make an object to emit light? l known how you can make an object to emit light in Blender render but l don't known how you can make an object to emit light in Blender game.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can, you could however parent a light to the object and give the object a shadeless texture. It for all intents and purposes would appear to be emitting light in that case.

Comment: Ah, yes l thought first of  this type of option but then l thought maiby there is a another way how to make an object to emit light but if so thank you for your answer.