# Is there a way to make an emission shader effect in blender engine?

Tags: materials, game-engine

I'm trying to remake these materials in the blender engine, I can do the grey one of course, but I have no idea how to make the emission ones, is there a way?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/blender-game-how-you-can-make-an-object-to-emit-light

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender game: How you can make an object to emit light?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34466/blender-game-how-you-can-make-an-object-to-emit-light)

Answer (score -1):

The best option is to switch to cycles and use the cycles emission shader. I am guessing you have never heard of it... you can do that by moving your cursor to the top and changing your render to cycles render. next go to your materials panel and click on the box that says diffuse and change it to an emission. If you need clarification on any of these steps just ask.

Comment: no, i actually made this on cycles but i need to remake it in blender engine, i guess i should've been more specific